# Methods of moving all of my local files into cloud storage

Tags: macos, file-management, file-sharing, file-transfer, amazon-s3

I have a large amount of data that I would like to move into cloud storage. Some of the files (~30 GB) are archived, but uncompressed, files (text, documents, images, videos, and other media). Other files are active files which I use at least every week. The active files vary from documents to images and weight in at ~70-100 GB.

Ideally the solution I am looking for would allow me to divide file storage amongst multiple storage endpoints (or "buckets", if you want to use an AWS term), so that work and personal files are separated. Server and/or client side file encryption is a huge concern. Files at an archival location should not be cached locally for offline use, however, active files should be.

The ability to use a cloud storage service where I control the account the files are stored on is a huge concern for me.

As far as commercial solutions go, I've looked at [JungleDisk](https://www.jungledisk.com/), but I am unsure whether or not it will fit my needs (especially those needs having to do with multiple storage endpoints).

I have also looked at the upcoming, open-source project [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/), but I don't know if it is stable and well-documented enough to suit my needs. I am more than comfortable with a command line, though, if there are similar, stable command line tools available.

Other solutions involving a server will not work. Thus solutions like [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/), which require a remote git repo or your own server, are out of the question.

The end goal after this entire migration to cloud storage is to clean my disc of static files. While I use OS X 10.7 (about to upgrade to 10.8) with Time Machine, I really like the idea of having an offsite backup that doubles as a syncing solution.

I know that Dropbox (and competitors) does a lot of what I am requesting, but their terms of service and privacy policies do not sit well with me.

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated!!

-Robert

Comment: why not Amazon S3? As far as I know it has encryption and as you said you can have multiple buckets with different users & access keys for different buckets.

Comment: The way this is worded is for a software recommendation and this sort of question is off-topic for SU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been satisfied with [Arq](http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/) to backup to Amazon S3. It doesn't necessarily separate your work and personal files, though.